# Xcode organizer validation issue

Tags: ios, xcode5

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

In Xcode, I set code signing to my distribution one for release, I set up the provisioning profile to the only one I have and I archive prior to validating in organizer.

```
the bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value, 
'com.xxxx.com.xxxx.ProjectNameWithoutSpaces'. if you want to change your 
bundle identifier etc.
```

NOTE how the com.xxx.com.xxx is shown twice in the error... My question is does the com.xxx.com.xxx indicated in the error come from itunesConnect or from my Xcode? Same for name without spaces for the project while in my Xcode it shows with spaces...

All my plist values are still the default ones.

Appreciate your help, spent considerable time on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundle Id in itunesConnect was com.xxx.com.xxxx.appNameWithoutSpaces...

This can be edited to remove the com.xxxx.

Also, for appWithoutSpaces, you can fix and use dashes instead of spaces...